# Change "Not in sudoers file, this incident will be reported" message?

Tags: sudo

Is it possible to edit this message that someone sees when a sudo command fails due to permissions problems?

Comment: Enabling insults (if support has been compiled into your version of sudo) `Defaults insults` will change the message, but not in customizable fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the only message you are allowed to configure with the sudo conf.

badpass_message="Sorry, try again."

Reference: http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html

However to answer your question you are more than welcome to compile your own copy of sudo.

This would be the message you are getting at the link below:
http://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/2c8b222a5f7f/plugins/sudoers/logging.c#l293